# How to upgrade cakephp version 1.3.* to 2.7.*?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I have developed a website using cakePHP version 1.3.14. But now I wanted to upgrade the cakephp version for my website because many function has been depreciated. I also follow the tutorial given on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html

after doing all this when i run the command **./Console/cake upgrade all** on my terminal all goes well, but when I am opening my website on browser it gives me **server error-500**. I have follow other tutorials as well but not able to upgrade my website's cakephp version. can anyone help me out from this situation and help me in upgrading my websites's cakephp version. Any help will be much appriciated.

Comment: Did you follow the migration process?

Comment: @Sougata i have followed the tutorial of the link mentioned above.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html & http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-7-migration-guide.html

Comment: i have followed the same link, but not able to upgrade my website.

Comment: The upgrade shell just helps you get started, but cannot possibly tackle all issues. 500 error means: Read the logs! That is going to be something you'll find yourself doing over the next couple of days anyway, as you would with any migration process (Check for errors, deprecations and such).

Answer (score 1):

I hope these link will be helpful for you.

**http://mark-story.com/posts/view/upgrading-to-cakephp-3-0**
**https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/pucWIOtrckY**

Comment: sorry @saumya  i have already read the article and tried to apply this. But not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to upgrade the cakephp from 1.x to 2.x. below is the official cakephp migration guide link, This link give you all the information which you required in migrations of your code base. Please follow this and let me know your experiance.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Thanks